# Detectar en que índice hay objetos

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, herencia, polimorfismo

Este método es el que uso para crear los enemigos en la interfaz. supongo que es un problema de coordenadas que son las que dicen i * 40 j * 40 esas son las que uso para dibujarlas en la interfaz

```
public void crearEnemigos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Nivel.aparicionVirus.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nivel.aparicionVirus.length; j++) {
                if (Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 1) {
                    casilla[i][j] = new Casilla();
                    casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaL(i * 40, j * 40));

                } // If

                if (Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 2) {
                    casilla[i][j] = new Casilla();
                    casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaS(i * 40, i * 40));

                } // If

                if (Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 3) {
                    casilla[i][j] = new Casilla();
                    casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaV(i * 40, j * 40));
                } // If
            } // For j

        } // For i
    } // Crear Enemigos
```

Rehago la pregunta con mejor formato y más sencillo todo, ya tengo el problema solucionado, ahora lo que pasa es que el virus se me creó en la casilla que no es, se hizo encima de otro virus y no en su casilla correspondiente, por ejemplo la se debe crear en la fila 2 y columna 3, pero se crea en la fila 1 y columna 1.

```
public void reproducirse() {
            for (int i = 0; i < casilla.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < casilla.length; j++) {
                    if (this.casilla[i][j] != null && this.casilla[i][j + 1] != null && this.casilla[i + 1][j] != null
                            && this.casilla[i + 1][j + 1] == null) {
                        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    
                        if (random >= 0 && random <= 5) {
                            casilla[i + 1][j + 1] = new Casilla();
                            this.casilla[i + 1][j + 1].setEnemigo(new CepaL(i * 40, j * 40));
                        } else if (random <= 8 && random >= 6) {
                            casilla[i + 1][j + 1] = new Casilla();
                            this.casilla[i + 1][j + 1].setEnemigo(new CepaS(i * 40, j * 40));
    
                        } else {
                            casilla[i + 1][j + 1] = new Casilla();
                            this.casilla[i + 1][j + 1].setEnemigo(new CepaV(i * 40, j * 40));
    
                        } // Else
    
                    } // If
                    if (this.casilla[i][j] != null && this.casilla[i][j + 1] != null && this.casilla[i + 1][j] == null
                            && this.casilla[i + 1][j + 1] != null) {
                        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    
                        if (random >= 0 && random <= 5) {
                            casilla[i + 1][j] = new Casilla();
                            this.casilla[i + 1][j].setEnemigo(new CepaL(i * 40, j * 40));
                        } else if (random <= 8 && random >= 6) {
                            casilla[i + 1][j] = new Casilla();
                            this.casilla[i + 1][j].setEnemigo(new CepaS(i * 40, j * 40));
    
                        } else {
                            casilla[i + 1][j] = new Casilla();
                            this.casilla[i + 1][j].setEnemigo(new CepaV(i * 40, j * 40));
    
                        } // Else
                    } // If
                } // For j
            } // For i
    
        } // Método para reproducir virus
```

Comment: Qué has intentado hacer de ese método?

Comment: por ejemplo en el método de crear enemigos, los seteo en las casillas. tuve de idea algo como esto.

Comment: voy a actualizar la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego código con explicación en comentarios.

```
public static boolean estaRodeado(int i, int j) {

    // variables que indican si un enemigo de ese tipo está rodeando la casilla
    boolean CepaL = false, CepaS = false, CepaV = false;

    // son 8 casillas las que rodean: arriba, abajo izquierda, derecha, y las 4 diagonales
    // entonces se calcula la posición de cada una de esas casillas
    int[][] coordenadas = new int[][]{
            {i + 1, j}, {i - 1, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}, {i - 1, j - 1},
            {i, j + 1}, {i, j - 1}, {i - 1, j + 1}, {i + 1, j - 1}
    };

    // se recorren las casillas que rodean
    for (int[] coordenada : coordenadas) {
        // se usa un try/catch para las excepciones cuando la casilla que rodea
        // este fuera del rango de la matriz
        try {
            // en cada iteración se evalúa si el objeto en la casilla es de alguno de los enemigos
            // la primer condición es para conservar el valor de la variable
            Object enemigo = casilla[coordenada[0]][coordenada[1]].getEnemigo();

            CepaL = CepaL || enemigo instanceof CepaL;
            CepaS = CepaS || enemigo instanceof CepaS;
            CepaV = CepaV || enemigo instanceof CepaV;

        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }

    }

    // si los tres enemigos están rodeando devolver true
    return CepaL && CepaS && CepaV;
}
```

Luego llamarlo:

```
if(estaRodeado(i, j)){

  // crear nuevo virus

}
```

Comment: La parte de coordenadas me hizo darme cuenta que tenía mal una parte de lógica antes ahora lo solucioné gracias a eso, te agradezco.